# Count $_POST reply starting by "custom_"

Tags: php, arrays, post

On my website, we can create a product with an unknown number of custom field. To insert my data inside the database, I want to know the number of inputs starting with "parameter" (in my data below).

How can I count() the POST result starting with "parameter"?
Thanks

```
array(6) {
    ["quantity"]=> string(8) "200"
    ["price"]=> string(4) "150"
    ["product_supplier"]=> string(4) "1"
    ["parameter1"]=> string(4) "text"
    ["parameter2"]=> string(7) "Exemple"
    ["parameter3"]=> string(4) "text"
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just send the count in the request? Or depending on how the data is input, use an array.

Comment: the data is from differents (between 0 and 10) input (its not on select)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the keys of the array, and then iterate through using a `foreach` or [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) e.g.

```
$count = 0;
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    if (strpos($key, 'parameter') === 0) $count++;
}
echo "$count parameters\n";

$count = array_reduce(array_keys($array), function ($c, $v) { 
    if (strpos($v, 'parameter') === 0) $c++; 
    return $c; },
    0);
echo "$count parameters\n";
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
3 parameters
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jTpm9)

You might instead want to consider naming your parameter inputs using PHP's array notation e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="parameters[]" />
```

Then all your parameter inputs will appear as an array in `$_POST['parameters']` and you can get the count easily via

```
echo count($_POST['parameters']);
```

It will probably make it easier to process the parameters too as you can use a simple `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_POST['parameters'] as $parameter) {
    // do stuff
}
```